# Mocking a class constant in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

Say I have the below component that sets a constant, `this.MAX_LENGTH` in the constructor.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

class Input extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // An example constant
    this.MAX_LENGTH = 1024;
  }

  render() {
    
    return (
      <label htmlFor="comment_body">
        <textarea
          className="comment-reply input-highlight-on-focus"
          type="input"
          name="comment[body]"
          id="comment_body"
          maxLength={this.MAX_LENGTH}
          value={this.props.value} />
      </label>
    )
  }

}

export default Input;
```

The `MAX_LENGTH` constant is used to set the max length of the `textarea`.

In my Jest specs I want to **mock the value of `this.MAX_LENGTH`, but I'm not sure how to set that mock.**

Here's how my Jest test looks (it uses `chai` and `enzyme` as testing helpers):

```
it('renders the textarea', () => {
  // Mock the constant here to set a custom value of 99
  // ????

  const wrapper = mount(<Input value={'foo'} />)
  const textarea = wrapper.find('.comment-reply').first();

  expect(textarea).to.have.attr('maxLength', '99');
});
```

What can I replace `????` with mock the value of the constant?

I tried reading through [ES6 Class Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks) in the Jest docs but it seemed to be around mocking a whole imported class and I'm not sure how it would apply to a single constant.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't mock a class without mocking the entire thing. Either assert that actual hardcoded value in the `constructor` (brittle test, I know), or put the `MAX_LENGTH` value inside a constants file and import it in both the class and the test file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using instance properties for constants is considered a bad practice; this is what static properties are for. This would be possible to mock as `Input.MAX_LENGTH = ...` before mounting the component:

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  static MAX_LENGTH = 1024;
  ...
}
```

Original value needs to be restored in `afterEach`.

Or at least making it read-only prototype property. This would be possible to mock as `jest.spyOn(Input, 'MAX_LENGTH', 'get').mockReturnValue(...)` before mounting the component:

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  get MAX_LENGTH() { return 1024 };
  ...
}
```

Without that, it needs to be mocked on component instance after initial render:

```
const wrapper = mount(<Input value={'foo'} />)
wrapper.instance().MAX_LENGTH = ...;
wrapper.setProps({});
...
```